# Query SQL select double id in one field

Tags: mysql, sql

Good Morning, I want to display all the names associated with an id field separated by commas.

I want to take all `complaint_type.name` in the complaint table which is `complaint.id_type_complaint`:

```
My expectation select result is : 
SELECT complaint.id, complaint.notes, complaint_type.name
FROM complaint
LEFT JOIN complaint_type ON complaint_type.id = complaint.id_complaint_type
result :
+-------------------------------
|1 | Wet and broke | Broke, Wet
|2 | Lost Goods    | Lost
+-------------------------------
```

```
(complaint_type table)
+---+--------+
|id | name   |
+---+--------+
|1  | Broke  |
|2  | Lost   |
|3  | Wet    |
+---+--------+

(complaint table)
+---------------------------------------+
| id | notes         | id_type_complain |
+---------------------------------------+
|1   | Wet and Broke | 1,3              |
|2   | Lost Goods    | 2                |
```

Comment: it's better to store the data in many-to-many relationship (not to use comma-separated string inside a table column)

Comment: Fix your data model!  It is totally broken.  You are storing numbers as string!.  You don't have properly declared foreign key relationships!  You have multiple values in a string!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got the answer. You can use `FIND_IN_SET()` and `GROUP_CONCAT()` to solve your problem:

```
SELECT c.id, c.notes, GROUP_CONCAT(t.name) AS complaint_names
FROM complaint AS c LEFT JOIN complaint_type AS t
ON FIND_IN_SET(t.id, c.id_type_complain)
GROUP BY c.notes
ORDER BY c.id
```

which will result:

```
+----------------------------------+
|id| notes         |complaint_names|
+----------------------------------+
|1 | Wet and broke | Broke, Wet    |
|2 | Lost Goods    | Lost          |
+----------------------------------+
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/85025f/18/2)

Comment: Thank you very much, you're so helpfull.

Comment: You really understand my problem, you're the best, Thankyou